# Update foreign key from csv file

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to set up a simple database for the first time using MySQL Workbench. I'd like to update the foreign keys of the `child` table based on the values of `parent_child.csv`. Here are the current MySQL tables I have right now.

parent table

```
id_num  parent_id
------------------
33      parent_1
29      parent_2
46      parent_3
17      parent_4
...     ...
```

child table

```
id_num  child_id  parent_id_num
--------------------------------
22      child_1   NULL
13      child_2   NULL
52      child_3   NULL
76      child_4   NULL
...     ...       ...
```

And here is what `parent_child.csv` looks like:

parent_child.csv

```
parent_id  child_id
--------------------
parent_1   child_3
parent_1   child_4
parent_2   child_1
...         ...
```

Here is what I'd like the updated `child` table to be:

child table

```
id_num  child_id  parent_id_num
--------------------------------
22      child_1   29
13      child_2   NULL
52      child_3   33
76      child_4   33
...     ...       ...
```

Assume that not all `parent_id` and `child_id`'s are in `parent_child.csv`. So not all child_id's get updated.

How would I go about doing this? Would it require me to create a parent_child table in MySQL?

Here's what I want to do in a nutshell:

for every child_id in parent_child.csv:

- get `child_id`'s `parent_id`
- find `parent_id`'s `id_num` using parent table
- replace `child_id`'s foreign key (referred to as `parent_id_num`, set currently to NULL) with the found parent id's `id_num`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the CSV table into MySQL, then you can:

```
update child
left join parent_child on child.child_id = parent_child.child_id
left join parent on parent_child.parent_id = parent_id
set child.parent_id_num = parent.id_num
```